# Jboss run mode choice with infinispan

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, infinispan

I am starting on a Jboss 7.1 project and considering infinispan for caching. What are the advantages/disadvantages(limitations) of running Jboss in standalone vs domain mode with infinispan? I appreciate any insights on this.

Answer (score 0):

Both `standalone` and `domain` modes can cluster. I believe the main point of `domain` mode is to allow you to administer an entire group of servers from one central point.

In `domain` mode you can do things like deploy an application once and all servers in the domain will deploy the app.

In `standalone` mode, you would have to deploy it on each individual machine.

I am running Infinispan caches on clustered servers in `standalone` mode. It may require extra steps (creating the same configured caches in multiple servers) but I find standalone mode to be simpler for my own use.

[Here](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/06/29/managing-cluster-nodes-in-domain-mode-of-jboss-as-7-eap-6/) is an article on domain mode (in a [series](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/06/21/clustering-in-jboss-as7eap-6/) on JBoss7 clustering) that explains it pretty well.